# How to search text file line by line for '/##/'?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, if-statement, line, enumerate

Im trying to search through text files line by line and if a line contains /##/ format, I want to print the line. I know the line I want will have this format because I'm trying to extract the date. Is there syntax for something like this? For example..

```
 if('/%d%d/' in line):
    print (line)
```

Is there something that I can use in between the two forward slashes that is equivalent to a digit 0-9? I have no problem searching the file line by line, here's my code:

```
items = os.listdir("C:/output3")
for names in items:
    if names.endswith(".txt"):
        with open('C:/output3/' + names) as currentFile:
            for i, line in enumerate(currentFile):
                line=line.rstrip()
                if('/%d%d/' in line):
                    print (line)
                else:
                    i = i + 1
```

Once I can extract the line I can use regex to search for digits in front/behind of the /'s. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re` package.
It provides the functions `search` and `match` which receives a pattern and a string as arguments.

```
search(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found.


match(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    a match object, or None if no match was found.
```

In the below example I'm assuming you want to get any two numbers surrounded by slashes, like `/12/` or `/45/`. Case you don't want to match the slashes, just remove them.

I chose to use `\d` twice as the pattern to two numbers, but it could be any other equivalent regex.

```
# Importing regex package
import re

# Your code here...

# Define a pattern to match
pattern = '/\d\d/'

# Check if re.search() returns an object
if re.search(pattern, line) is not None:
    print(line)
```

Comment: For some reason when I use 'if re.match(pattern, line) is not None: print line, nothing prints. If I use the example below without the forward slashes /, it'll print lines where 2 digits are in the line.. Ideas?

Comment: Scratch that, I was just experimenting and tried replacing re.match with re.search, worked perfectly. Could someone explain the difference?

Comment: `search`: Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern.
`match`: Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string.

The best choice is the `search`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You came close! The `\d` sequence matches a digit (0-9). Here's how to use it in a regular expression for your script:

```
import re 
...
if re.match('\d\d', line) is not None 
    print(line)
```

`re.match` matches from the beginning of the string, so we don't need to use the `^` anchor as we might in another language. We can use `re.search` if we don't want to match from the beginning.

We can also avoid regular expressions by simply checking if the first two characters of the line are numbers:

```
if line[:2].isdigit() 
    print(line)
```

The `[:2]` takes a substring with a length of two from the beginning of the string.

Here's an implementation of the above that you can use directly from the command line:

```
type C:\output3\*.txt | python -c 'import sys;[[sys.stdout.write(line)] for line in sys.stdin if line.rstrip()[:2].isdigit()]'
```

`type` is a built in command in windows. We're just using it here to get the contents of any *.txt* files in that directory. We then pipe the output of `type` to python which invokes a mini version of your script.